# Selecting a range of columns in a stacked chart and retrieving the related data

Tags: angular, typescript, fusioncharts

I am trying to create a stacked chart where the columns represent time, where I can set a range and where I can retrieve data from the columns within that range.

[This image is a good example of what the chart should look like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3b4v.png)

Using the example above I want to be able to set a range between March and July and be able to retrieve the data from the columns within that range. The range would in practice be an x axis version of the Reference Zone.

Is something along these lines possible and if so what would the required events be? The current method I am considering attempting is using the chartClick event to try and set a range.

Related to this question is dragging and dropping a element outside the chart possible? The examples I've seen have been restricted to the chart itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your x-axis is time-based hence time-series charts would be the best choice in this case along with that you can use the selection change event which could fetch the data within that date range: https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/fusiontime/api/fusiontime-events#selectionchange

Based on your requirements here is a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/o4kw8ra5/

```
 events: {
      "selectionChange": function(ev) {
        console.log(ev.data.start, ev.data.end);
      }
    }
```

The above snippet will return you the start and end time stamp selection using which you can filter out the data.